# Email On Results Of Query On Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that gets the 2 newest datetime values. I need to get a diff of the datetime and email if the value is greater than 5 minutes. I have accomplished it using 3 tables but i would like to do it in a single query.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, T1, T2) + 10 As DIFF
FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 T1.DateAndTime As T1,  T2.DateAndTime AS T2 

FROM [WIMS_SQL].[dbo].[FloatTable] as T1


Inner Join [WIMS_SQL].[dbo].[FloatTable] as T2

On T1.DateAndTime > T2.DateAndTime 

Order By  T2.DateAndTime Desc)

IF DIFF > 5 "EMAIL FUNCTION"
```

Im sure theres a better way to do this than i am using

Comment: Diff will always be > 5 because you are adding 10...or are your datetime functions backwards?

Comment: Is there a question about an error here, or are you just trying to code-golf this?

Comment: @scsimon the DATEDIFF result is always negative because he has t1>t2 in the join then gets the diff from t1 to t2.

Comment: I think the datetime function is backwards

Comment: I do not know what code-golf means

Comment: It means to write code in as few strokes as possible.

Comment: Sorry guess i should have mentioned im farily new to SQL beyond simple queries

Comment: OK yes i am trying to code-golf it. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: good catch @JiggsJedi. easy solve for this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the logic with a CTE.

```
declare @minutes int

;with cte as(
    select top 2 DateAndTime
    from [WIMS_SQL].[dbo].[FloatTable]
    order by DateAndTime desc)


select 
    @minutes = datediff(minute, max(DateAndTime), min(DateAndTime)) + 10
from cte

if (@minutes > 5)    
begin
    exec msdb..sp_send_dbmail
         @profile_name = 'Profile Name You Set Up'
        ,@recipients = 'someone@domain.com'
        ,@subject = 'some subject'
end
```

**[ONLINE DEMO](http://rextester.com/PSJWS34185)**

This method will prevent you from making a cartesian product with that join condition and should be a lot faster.

Comment: Thank you this worked great with a couple modifications. I have several of the same datetime values so i did "SELECT Distinct TOP 2' and had to modify the mail script because im currently using SQL Express. What is CTE?

Comment: common table expression